# VBA Copy a file as a different file extension

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a data formatter where the user selects a file of type .xlsx and then I format it and save it as type .csv. I am needing to convert the xlsx file to a csv before I can format it. To do this, I couldn't find anything apart from opening the file, copying the used range to a worksheet on the original file, saving that worksheet as csv and then referencing that file. Despite a lack of elegance, this would work fine for the use case. However, I cannot seem to get the copying of the worksheet to be formatted down.

Here's what I'm trying for copying:

```
        Dim active As Worksheet
        Set active = ActiveSheet
        
        With Workbooks.Open(myFile)
            ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
            active.Paste
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
```

This, in theory, should copy the data from the file being opened to the already opened file, but it doesn't.

Comment: Why not open the file, then save as csv instead of copy/pasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works great for me:

**As a sub:**

```
Sub ConvertToCSV()
    
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim WBtmp As Workbook
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    MyFile = "C:\Users\cameron\Documents\IDs.xlsx"
    Set WBtmp = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
    With WBtmp
        .SaveAs Replace(MyFile, ".xlsx", ""), xlCSV
        .Close
    End With
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

**Or as a function**

```
Sub TestFunc()
    fConvertToCSV "C:\Users\cameron\Documents\IDs.xlsx"
End Sub
Function fConvertToCSV(MyFile As String)
    
    Dim WBtmp As Workbook
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Set WBtmp = Workbooks.Open(MyFile)
    With WBtmp
        .SaveAs Replace(MyFile, ".xlsx", ""), xlCSV
        .Close
    End With
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Function
```